# Multiple UITableViewcontrollers in iOS app & subclassing

Tags: ios, uitableview, subclass

I'm working on Stanford's CS193P iOS course and in one of the assignments, we need multiple UITableViews. In the assignment notes, the instructor said:

> "And use your awesome object-oriented programming design skills to be
>   certain to reuse as much code as possible. Many of the MVC’s in this
>   application are very similar. It is perfectly fine to create a
>   subclass of UITableViewController to do something, then create a
>   subclass of that class to do something slightly more refined."

So rather than having

```
@interface myFirstTableViewController : UITableViewController
```

and

```
@interface mySecondTableViewController : UITableViewController
```

he's implying we use:

```
@interface myFirstTableViewController : UITableViewController
```

and

```
@interface mySecondTableViewController : myFirstTableViewController
```

When I do it this way, `mySecondTableViewController` has only the following methods:

```
initWithNibName
viewDidLoad
didReceiveMemoryWarning
```

What's happening here? In `mySecondViewController`, do I need to only implement those methods that are different to `myFirstTableViewController` (maybe making a slight change and then calling the `super` version?

Also, is this the correct way to do things or is it best to have each of my custom tvcs as a separate subclass of UITableViewController?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The more likely pattern would be:

```
@interface CommonTableViewController : UITableViewController
...
@interface FirstTableViewController : CommonTableViewController
...
@interface SecondTableViewController : CommonTableViewController
```

It's difficult to set context-free rules, however; it really depends on how much similar code can be moved into the common parent.  (And the way you structured things isn't necessarily wrong either if `mySecondTableViewController` does everything `myFirstTableViewController` does, plus a little more.)

Comment: Thanks. So maybe put all the genuinely common code in 'CommonTableViewcontroller' and the actually different code in 'first' and 'second'?

Comment: New to all this and just started to play with my code and now know that for any methods I don't implement in mySecondTableViewController, the super version is called.

Comment: Right.  With inheritance the child is everything its parent is, along with anything it explicitly says it does in addition...or anything it explicitly says it does differently (i.e. overrides).

Comment: Ok, it appears that subclassing may not be the right thing to do in this particular case, as I'm either having to compromise my code (property names, etc) in order to be able to use my superclass' methods or implement the same methods again, in which case I could've just used a separate subclass of UITableViewController. But I have learnt a few things :-)

Comment: This answer helped me figure out how to do what I needed. I am trying figure out how to reuse the same subclass for two different storyboard uitableviewcontroller instances, with some differences between each. Both have common code as well, so I didn't want to make a duplicate class. I now see that I can have a common subclass, then subclass off that 2 different ways! Thanks!